What's the best way to get a type with only the string representations of boolean values?
Using an API that takes a boolean value, but only its string representation (i.e. "true" and "false" instead of true and false values). Is there a neat way to just enumerate the boolean values as strings and make them a type?
Wrote type StringBoolean = "true" | "false" and it works, but seems a little silly in my opinion. I'm hoping for something along the lines of: type StringBoolean = boolean.values as string

This can be done using template literal types to serialize boolean as a union of string literal types:
type StringUnion = `${boolean}`
// ^? type StringUnion = "false" | "true"

Playground link to code
